# Cannot destructure property of object from context as it is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use the useContext hook in my react app to manage the cart state but I don't know why am I getting this error again and again that the function that I'm trying to destructure is undefined.

I'm new to using context API please help me with the same. I saw other answers related to context API and tried everything like exporting the CartContext as default and then importing it without destructoring but nothing worked. I'm neither able to import the functions nor the data.

Here is my CartContext.js file

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import CartReducer from "./CartReducer";

//Initialized Context
export const CartContext = createContext();

export const CartProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(CartReducer, products);

  function addProductWithQuantity(product) {
    dispatch({
      type: "ADD_PRODUCT",
      payload: {
        product,
        quantity: 1,
      },
    });
  }

  const deleteProductWithId = (id) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "DELETE_PRODUCT",
      payload: id,
    });
  };

  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        state,
        addProductWithQuantity,
        deleteProductWithId,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

And here is the file where I'm using the useContext.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  Typography,
  Tooltip,
  IconButton,
  Button,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./Product.module.css";
import amazon from "../../icons/amazon-brands.png";
import flipkart from "../../icons/flipkart.png";
import { SnackbarProvider, useSnackbar } from "notistack";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { CartContext } from "../../Context/CartContext";

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={3} preventDuplicate>
      <ProductCard product={product} />
    </SnackbarProvider>
  );
};

export default Product;

const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  const {
    id,
    imageUrls,
    storeName,
    category,
    price,
    amazonLink,
    flipkartLink,
    title,
  } = product;

  const iconColor = "var(--primaryColor)";

  const { addProductWithQuantity } = useContext(CartContext); //Throws an error always

  console.log(addProductWithQuantity);

  const gotoURL = (location) => {
    let a = document.createElement("a");
    a.target = "_blank";
    a.href = location;
    a.click();
  };

  const handleClickVariant = (variant, title, id) => () => {
    enqueueSnackbar(`Successfully added ${title} to cart`, {
      variant,
    });
    onClickHeart(id);
    // saveToLocal();
    addProductWithQuantity(product);
  };

  const saveToLocal = () => {
    let oldCart = localStorage.getItem("cart");
    let newCart = oldCart ? JSON.parse(oldCart) : [];
    newCart.push(product);
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(newCart));
  };

  const onClickHeart = (id) => {
    document
      .getElementById(id)
      .style.setProperty("color", iconColor, "important");
  };

  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

  return (
    <Card key={id} className={styles.card}>
      <Link to={`/products/${id.trim()}`} className={styles.noDecoration}>
        <div className={styles.thumbnail}>
          <img src={imageUrls[0]} alt={title} />
        </div>
      </Link>
      <div className={styles.name}>
        <Typography className={styles.category} variant="subtitle2">
          {category}
        </Typography>
        <Link to={`/products/${id.trim()}`} className={styles.noDecoration}>
          <Typography className={styles.company} variant="subtitle1">
            {title}
          </Typography>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.priceLike}>
        <h4>₹{price}</h4>
        <Tooltip title="Add to favourites" placement="top">
          <IconButton
            onClick={handleClickVariant("success", title, id)}
            className={styles.likeIcon}
          >
            <i id={id} className={classNames("fas fa-cart-plus")} />
          </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.buttons}>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={styles.amazonBtn}
          onClick={() => gotoURL(amazonLink)}
        >
          <img src={amazon} alt="amazon-link" /> amazon.in
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          className={styles.flipkartBtn}
          onClick={() => gotoURL(flipkartLink)}
        >
          <img src={flipkart} alt="flipkart-link" />
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};

}
```

Comment: @pilchard I think it's not about exporting an object, because when I do `import CartContext` it gives me an error that CartContext is not a default export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I forgot to wrap my routes with CartContext Provider.
Here is what I did,

```
import CartProvider from '../CartContext';

return(
 <CartProvider>
   ... Routes
 <CartProvider>
)
```